# Unable to run rails console using Docker Compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, docker-compose

Im quite new to Docker and have started using Docker Compose to run my rails 4 application in development on my OS X 10.10 machine. The rails app works fine but if i try to run the rails console using the command below:

```
docker-compose run web bundle exec rails console
```

or

```
docker-compose run web rails console
```

I get the following error:

> Could not find CFPropertyList-2.3.1 in any of the sources Run `bundle
>   install` to install missing gems.

I tried doing `docker-compose run web bundle install`, but i continue to get the same error. What could be the reason behind this ?. Below are my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml .

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs npm nodejs-legacy
RUN npm install -g phantomjs

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  mailcatcher:
    image: yappabe/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1025:1025"
      - "1080:1080"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
      - mailcatcher
```

Answer (score 36):

You must use inside the root folder this:

```
docker-compose exec web rails console
```

Answer (score 4):

to access to rails console you need the docker command, not docker-compose.
first run

```
docker ps
```

to find the CONTAINER ID (for example 916703608c5e), then run docker exec with that container id:

```
docker exec -ti 916703608c5e rails console production
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You can certainly use docker-compose to run commands for the services it has set up.

Comment: @x1a4  thats intresting - can you please give a correct answer to the question then?

Comment: I mean, cool if there's a docker-compose function too, but as long as we're talking about a non-docker-compose function, I found doing the above worked,  except instead of gitlab-rails, I just used rails.  Are you using some kind of gitlab-specific version of rails?

Comment: @MikeBelanger: oops, yes I was. thanks, I edited the post to remove this

Answer (score 4):

First, try rebuilding the image with:

```
docker-compose build web
```

Or 
force if it doesn't work: `docker-compose build web --no-cache`

Try doing it again:

```
docker-compose run web rails console
```

If that didn't work, you can always tap into the shell:

```
docker-compose run web sh
```

And then run:

```
rails console
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ docker-compose exec web rails console
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"rails\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown


$ docker-compose exec web bundle exec rails console    
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.2.2)
irb(main):001:0>
```

Solution

`$ docker-compose exec web rails console`

or

`docker-compose exec web bundle exec rails console`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the Party, but the above didn't work for me. I was receiving the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"rails\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

But the following fixed it for me:

`docker-compose exec <container> bundle exec rails console`